# Using Application Request Routing in this issue

Tags: asp.net, .net, url, arr

There is a website with these links
OldUrl:  http://Example.com/Archive/Newsdetails.aspx?NewsID=123&Obj=1&title=mytitle

New website for this (Example.com) Urls are completely different.
NewUrl:  http://Example.com/?news/985698/6523687/856987/mytitle

How can I rout from OldUrl to NewUrl only with using ARR ?

Comment: You can't, unless you want to harcode the `/985698/6523687/856987/` part. Where should those numbers come from?

Comment: It means , first number:pageID , second number: WebpartID (which make template form the page) , Third number is RecordID .... all numbers in NewUrl are different from OldUrl

Answer (score 0):

You can route for you application in `RegisterRoutes` method like :

```
void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.MapPageRoute("Archive",
        "news/{NewsId}/{Obj}/{title}",
        "~/Newsdetails.aspx", true,
        new RouteValueDictionary { 
            { "NewsId, "@"\d{6}" }, 
            { "Obj", "@"\d{7}" },
            { "title", "@[a-z]{100}" }
         });
}
```

for more details refer msdn link for routing on asp.net webforms:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd329551.aspx

Comment: I have to use ARR ( https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/application-request-routing )

Comment: I can not edit the source code , I only access to Web.config and IIS